# Whirring Sound in the Engine Bay

Tags: engine, chevrolet, noise, cobalt

So my cobalt LS 2006 has about ~100K miles. Today, literally two hours ago it started making a whirring not whining noise kinda sounds like a vacuum clear sound, its a very faint noise. The noise exists only between 10-25mph, past that it stops. Its not the tires, i put the car in neutral and reved a few times.

I plan on topping off the transmission fluid.

What are the possible problems?

Comment: This could be so many different things. Can you tell what are is it coming from; inside engine compartment, by the wheels, back of the car, etc.? What have you checked? What does topping off the transmission fluid have to do with your question? Do you suspect the transmission? If so, why?

Comment: Its coming from inside the engine bay, left hand side by the belts, from what i have deduced. I cant top off the transmission fluid as some engineer thought it was a good idea to seal it in the cobalt series of cars and have a mechanic always do it. I only suspected transmission as the car is old and has a number of miles on it, and it would be time to change out the fluid. Now im thinking its a failing alternator. Yet, i dont see any power issues on my dash like dimming lights and such. Here is a clip: 13 seconds in: https://soundcloud.com/amanda-archer-940279718/whirring1

Comment: It seems as though it might be a timing belt being too tight issue. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IMT-CbtLqeU&t=6m59s

Comment: Not likely the timing belt, unless you had it serviced. They tend to loosen, not tighten with age. To me, it sounds like an alternator, idler pulley or power steering pump.

Comment: I had the timing belt replaced April 29.